# Почему при вызове csv.reader в результате получается список из одной строки, если в строках файла есть данные с кавычками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv  
with open(r'C:\file.csv') as c:  
   data = csv.reader(c, delimiter=',')  
    for i in data:  
      print(i)
```

При таком вызове, если в строке файла есть данные с кавычками, то в результате получаем следующее:

```
['2394487,HH704662,10/10/2002 11:03:40 AM,002XX S LAFLIN ST,2860,PUBLIC PEACE VIOLATION,FALSE POLICE REPORT,"SCHOOL, PUBLIC, BUILDING",false,false,1211,012,2,28,24']
```

В списке только одна строка. В остальных строках без кавычек, получаю данные в виде списка строк.

Comment: можете привести в ответе "проблемную" строку в ее исходном виде - так как она сохранена в CSV файле? Подозреваю, что у вас поломанный CSV... Кстати что происходит с этой строкой если открыть этот файл в Excel?

Comment: пример строки, которая обрабатывается неправильно: 2393397,HH691150,10/04/2002 08:00:00 AM,037XX W POLK ST,0460,BATTERY,SIMPLE,"SCHOOL, PUBLIC, BUILDING",true,false,1133,011,24,27,08B

Comment: пример строки которая обрабатывается правильно:    2393993,HH705004,10/09/2002 10:00:00 PM,052XX S MAY ST,1320,CRIMINAL DAMAGE,TO VEHICLE,STREET,false,false,0934,009,16,61,14

Comment: в excel, все нормально открывается. Когда удалил кавычки, каждое слово внутри кавычек добавилось в список в качестве отдельной строки

Comment: попробуйте явно указать символ квотирования: `csv.reader(c, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')`

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что у вас сломанный/некорректный CSV файл, т.к. если бы он был правильным, то `csv.reader()` правильно бы его прочитал.

Пример

Исходный CSV файл (обратите внимание на первое поле в последней строке, где в ячейке присутствуют запятые (разделитель)):

```
name,zip
First Bank,12345
"Jhonson, Brenson, Eriksson and brothers",98765
```

В таких случаях все значение ячейки нужно заключить в кавычки - символ квотирования и тогда `csv.reader()` правильно разберет данные:

```
import csv

filename = r"D:\download\test.csv"

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Вывод:

```
['name', 'zip']
['First Bank', '12345']
['Jhonson, Brenson, Eriksson and brothers', '98765']
```

PS по умолчанию в качестве символа квотирования используется символ двойной кавычки (`"`), но можно использовать и другой. Для этого его необходимо указать явно:

```
csv.reader(..., quotechar="|")
```